# How to tell GCC there is no pointer aliasing for loop auto-vectorization? (Restrict doesn't work)

Tags: c, gcc, auto-vectorization

I am having problems getting GCC to vectorize this loop:

```
register int_fast8_t  __attribute__ ((aligned)) * restrict fillRow = __builtin_assume_aligned(rowMaps + query[i]*rowLen,8);
    register int  __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) *restrict curRow = __builtin_assume_aligned(scoreMatrix + i*rowLen,16), 
         __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) *restrict prevRow = __builtin_assume_aligned(curRow - rowLen,16);
    register unsigned   __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) *restrict shiftCur = __builtin_assume_aligned(shiftMatrix + i*rowLen,16), 
        __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) *restrict shiftPrev = __builtin_assume_aligned(shiftCur - rowLen,16);
    unsigned j; 

    unsigned *restrict  diagShift = shiftPrev - 1;
    int *restrict diagScore = prevRow - 1;
     for (j=1; j < rs; ++j) {
        curRow[j] = diagScore[j] + fillRow[j];
        shiftCur[j] = diagShift[j]; 

    }
```

These variables come from two matrices (scoreMatrix and shiftMatrix, which are declared aligned and are guaranteed to have each "row" start aligned), as well as an 8-bit array (fillRow). GCC keeps telling me:

```
prog.c:600:4: note: === vect_analyze_data_ref_dependences ===
prog.c:600:4: note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_90 and *_89
prog.c:600:4: note: mark for run-time aliasing test between *_90 and *_89
prog.c:600:4: note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *_98 and *_97
prog.c:600:4: note: mark for run-time aliasing test between *_98 and *_97
```

Where line 600 is the loop in question. I don't know how to make it any more explicit that there is no aliasing going on. Previously I left out the diagShift and diagScore lines and just had the loop index, for instance, prevRow[j-1] instead of "diagShift[j]" -- exact same result. What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you typedef those because they are hard to read.

Comment: You don't need the `register` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Only shown here to be clear there isn't something weird going on in the typedef. Also, I'm using register because variables tagged "register" should not have their address accessible by anything (and hence no aliasing).

Comment: You can always manually create a vector type `typedef int v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));` so you can control the vectors yourself.

Comment: That is a great piece of advice. I was worried about the portability of these types outside GCC (in fact, I'm also worried about the GCC-specific alignment declarations in the above code). Also, I haven't really seen a good guide for how to use them. If I were to guess at what v4si means, v4 = vector of 4, i = integer, I guess.

Comment: Do you actually need all the `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` and the `__builtin_assume_aligned()`?  I'd get rid of these if you safely can, and also of the `register` keywords.  I don't think `restrict` is useful for local variables, either, but I guess it's not harmful.

Comment: The `v4si` typedef will be 16 byte aligned and gcc will automatically generate simd instructions for it when doing arithmetic operations.

Comment: @user1649948 " I was worried about the portability" - you're already using non portable code anyways.

Comment: @user1649948 - Heres a link worth reading if you haven't yet. [GCC Vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)

Comment: @user1649948 " I was worried about the portability" - It seems like your worried more about performance than portability in this case.

Comment: @user1649948 What tool did you use to point out this code as a bottleneck?

Comment: I can take off everything but the __builtin_assume_aligned and get the same generated code. Without the assume_aligned, the "Calculated minimum iters for profitability" goes from 10 (which is too high IMO) to 27.

Comment: This code is a bottleneck because it is the core of my program, where I am filling this matrix over and over. If I replace it with dummy code the program runs instantly. ;)

Comment: I would probably make all of the arrays of `v4si` type.

Comment: If you have an x86 processor and really want to get down and dirty. Look at this [GCC X86  Instrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html) and do the SIMD instructions.  You can probably get some optimizations down better than the compiler in some cases.

Comment: Use icc if you want a better vectorizing C compiler for x86.

Comment: I will try using v4si if I can find answers to my last few questions about them: 1) Can I cast an arbitrary aligned array to the v4si type? 2) How can I move all elements in a vector one position to the left, saving the result to a new vector? (It's okay if I lose the left-most value and introduce gibberish on the right.)

Comment: Added the last to its own question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595366/gcc-c-vector-extension-how-to-shift-contents-of-a-vector-to-the-left-by-one-ele).

Comment: the posted code doesn't even begin to compile (nearly 30 errors and warnings using gcc with -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99)  You state that the code takes a very long time to run, as posted.  Since the posted code does not even begin to compile.... how can it be running?

Comment: It compiles, but needs the matrices referred to in the declarations. I left them out for brevity. I describe them immediately after the code, if that helps!